# Connecting AppEngine Module to a custom DNS

Tags: google-app-engine, module, subdomain, yaml

I've been having troubles trying to connect a module to my custom domain.

I works perfectly on the appspot domain but not on my custom domain.

E.G.

http://m.myappname.appspot.com calls the dispatch.yaml file which routes the request to my mobile frontend

BUT

http://m.myappcustomdomain.com serves the default module (app.yaml)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could an entry like this in your `dispatch.yaml` file:

```
  - url: "m.myappcustomdomain.com/*"
    module: your_mobile_module
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. My former url value was "*/m.myappcustomdomain.com/*"