# Can I point a domain at a google app engine service?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have two very simple services set up (in python) on google app engine. I have a site which has been up for a while as the `defualt` service of my `example` project, and I just deployed another service, lets call it `foo`. I have dns forwarding working for the default service, so I can go to `example.com` (which I own in this hypothetical scenario) and see my default service. I can also go to `foo.example.appspot.com` and see my `foo` service, which works at the url.

I have also registered another domain, let's call it `foo.com`. What I want is for `foo.com` to use my `foo.example.appspot.com` service. To make matters trickier, `foo.com` has a bunch of sub-domains of it's own, so I need `x.foo.com` to go to my `foo` service as well (and even `x.y.foo.com` would be ideal, but if that is hard I can work around that one easily enough by just substituting out another character so it would be `x-y.foo.com` or something along those lines).

I'm pretty new to web dev (which is honestly a generous description for this simple project), but Iv'e spent a while reading and googling and haven't found a solution to this, so any advice would be helpful. My last resort would be to un-service-ify (if you will) the two services, and just bundle it all up into one big `main.py` which routes differently depending on the domain, and then point both domains at the `default` service. The big downside to this is that I already have everything working with services (which seems like a better approach).

I expect to get very few users so scaling isn't really an issue (though it's always interesting to learn about).

EDIT:

attempted to create a `dispatch.yaml` file to solve this as follows:

```
dispatch:

  - url: "foo.com"
    module: foo

  - url: "*.foo.com"
    module: foo
```

but when I run `appcfg.py -A <project_id_here> update_dispatch .` it says

```
Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to assign value 'foo.com' to attribute 'url':
invalid url 'foo.com'
  in "./dispatch.yaml", line 3, column 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it *should* be possible. I didn't actually use 2 different top-level domains, but the development console appears to be ready to accept a second one (I can't actually check as I don't own a 2nd domain). Follow the [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) procedure.

Pay special attention to the [Wildcard mappings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#wildcard_mappings) section - since your `foo.com` domain already has sub-domains in use you can't use wildcards at/above those sub-domains, you'll have to specify the desired subdomains.

The procedure only maps (sub)domains to the app as a whole, not to individual services/modules. You'll also have to use a [dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dispatchref), to route the specific subdomains to the corresponding modules/services. You can find examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103486/4495081 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081 (the last one has rules to allow the module to work on the custom domain, on `appspot.com` and on the local development server).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, dispatch files look like what I want, but I couldn't set up the mappings I wanted (see my edit above). I also tried using `"foo.com/"` and `"foo.com/*"`, all gave the same error message. Any thoughts? EDIT: sorry hold on a sec, I think the second link may have what I need

Comment: nope, I can't find an example routing a second entire domain `foo.com` to a service

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work following The links in the answer. My dispatch file wound up looking like this:

```
dispatch:

  - url: "foo.com/*"
    module: foo

  - url: "*.foo.com/*"
    module: foo
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my theory that multiple top-level domains can be mapped to a single app :)

Comment: Thanks for following up!